# Delphi - EAcessViolation Error

Tags: arrays, delphi, memory, dynamic

So guys... I've read aroung A LOT and I've tried using addons like madExcept (which I'm new to) but I've so far been unable to determine whats causing my errors.

**I'm getting EAccessViolation Exceptions on my code when calling SetLength() at seemingly random times. I have been unable to determine the reason behind it and I can't even track it down to a single line of code. I'd like you to please help me sort it out.**

This function is supposed to look for repeated patterns in a number array and count them.
Currently, its logic is still not 100% ready, but I want to correct these bugs before I proceed.

An example of how it will work when done:

Given the array {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5}, the function it will compare the subarray (1, 2, 3) to all other possible subarrays like (4, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3) and (2, 3, 5), counting the cases when they are the same. The function will then proceed to the next length and begin once again by comparing (1, 2, 3, 4) to (1, 2, 3, 5)...

- The maximum array lenght is 45.
- The minimum subarray length is 3.
- **The EAccessViolation error usually happens at array length 12-13 and usually at the last iteration of the first loop.**

Once again, I know there are flaws on the algorithm logic itself, but I really wanna fix the memory stuff first.

Thank you very much.

```
function TfrmMain.Ready(Numbers: Array of SmallInt): SmallInt;
var
  i: Integer;
  Length, MinLength, MaxLength: SmallInt;
  Array1, Array2: Array of SmallInt;
  Array1Pos, Array1FirstPos, Array1LastPos: Integer;
  Array2Pos, Array2FirstPos, Array2LastPos: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  MinLength := 3;
  MaxLength := Trunc( (High(Numbers) + 1 ) / 2 );

  for Length := MinLength to MaxLength do
  begin
    SetLength(Array1, 0);
    SetLength(Array2, 0);

    SetLength(Array1, Length);

    Array1FirstPos := 0;
    Array1LastPos  := High(Numbers) - High(Array1);

    for Array1Pos := Array1FirstPos to Array1LastPos do
    begin
      for i := Array1Pos to Length + Array1Pos do
        Array1[i - Array1Pos] := Numbers[i];

      if ( High(Array2) + 1 <> Length ) then
        SetLength(Array2, Length);

      Array2FirstPos := Array1Pos + Length;
      Array2LastPos  := High(Numbers);

      if ( ( Array1Pos >= Array2FirstPos ) and ( Array1Pos + Length <= Array2LastPos ) ) then
        for Array2Pos := Array2FirstPos to Array2LastPos do
        begin
          for i := Array2Pos to Length + Array2Pos do
            Array2[i - Array2Pos] := Numbers[i];

          if CompareArrays(Array1, Array2) then
            Result := Result + 1;
        end;
    end;
  end;

  SetLength(Array1, 0);
  SetLength(Array2, 0);
end;

function TfrmMain.CompareArrays(Array1, Array2: Array of SmallInt): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
    Result := false;

  if ( High(Array1) <> High(Array2) ) then
    Exit;

  for i := 0 to High(Array1) do
    if ( Array1[i] <> Array2[i] ) then
        Exit;

    Result := true;
end;
```

**SOLVED! Thanks Jeferson Oliveira!**

Comment: How are you invoking the "Ready" method (with which parameters) when the error occurs? In which line the exception is raised?

Comment: @Jeferson Oliveira
I get a Memo.Text, apply ExtractStrings to on it to remove whitespace then proceed to fill a SmallInt array by casting each members of the ShortString array.
The exception is raised at random SetLengths. Sometimes it happens in the middle of the code, somestimes after the last one...

Thanks for the attention, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error raising depends on the content of the arrays your are passing, so would be better if you could show us a calling example, or the content of your Memo.

Anyway, analyzing your code, I can see some things:

In the line below:

```
  if ( High(Array2) + 1 <> Length ) then
    SetLength(Array2, Length);
```

If Length = 0, or Length = High(Array2) + 1, the Array2 Length will not be defined.

Thus, when the code below is executed:

```
  if ( ( Array1Pos >= Array2FirstPos ) and ( Array1Pos + Length <= Array2LastPos ) ) then
    for Array2Pos := Array2FirstPos to Array2LastPos do
    begin
      for i := Array2Pos to Length + Array2Pos do
        Array2[i - Array2Pos] := Numbers[i];
```

If the length of Array2 is not yet defined, you could have and AccessViolation.
So (for the only purpose of fix this code), you should test the length of Array2 before try to access its index, with:

```
for i := Array2Pos to Length + Array2Pos do
begin
    if ((i - Array2Pos) >= System.Length(Array2) - 1) then
        Array2[i - Array2Pos] := Numbers[i];
end;
```

But I believe that focusing on your logic and organizing some test values you will see that are a lot of improvement to be done to your code that will, themselves, solve the current AV.

**Edited:** as your variable has the same name of the global function "Length", I updated the sample code to use the "namespace" System.

Comment: You, sir, are godsend.

My mistake was exactly what you mentioned, but with Array1 instead of Array2.
Took me long enough to notice and now I feel stupid, haha.

Thank you very much for your support. I know the logic flaws and I'm gonna fix them right now. 

Once again, thank you very much!